# Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl() is not returning the exact order of url params

Tags: order, sort

[image]I have implemented a code to get a URL parameters posted on custom site.The controller associated with custom site has `Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl()` method.

For my implementation, It is very necessary to get URL parameter as it is which has posted. But this `getURL()` method sorting the order of parameters alphabetically. So i am stuck to move further.

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: If possible, you should refactor your code to not depend on the order of parameters in the URL's query string. Depending on the order (which you don't have much, if any, control over) makes your solution very fragile, and likely to break in the future. Also, is there a reason why you can't use the `getParameters()` method of the `PageReference` class?

Comment: You may need to use like @DerekF suggested else use javascript to get current page url `window.location.href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Derek suggested. I personally prefer that idea. If you still need then below is Answer.

```
URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().getQuery() //this will return all your parameters
```

or

Use **`URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm()`** to get URL

```
public class oppCtrl {
    public String str {get;set;}
    public oppCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        str = URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm();
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" extensions="oppCtrl">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >{!str} 
            <script>
            alert(window.location.href );
            </script>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

or use in javascript **`window.location.href`**

[image]

After discussion with [**@Rishi**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/27356/rishi). Issue was, **developer mode was checked.  It needs to be unchecked to get a required url**

Comment: I have tried all of the methods you have provided. Every method is responding with some random parameter order . I have attached a screen shot below.

Comment: have you tried `URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().getQuery()`? I have tested this in my org. You can see the image. It is giving exact one

Comment: yes. I did. Actually I could not attach a screenshot. I can send u a link and its output by methods that u suggested.
link : https://phil.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/Paypal_IPN?transaction_subject=200703030249937&txn_type=web_accept&payment_date=23%3A36%3A36+Jan+11%2C+2014+PST&last_name=Balsom&residence_country=AU

Output getting : https://phil.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/Paypal_IPN?last_name=Balsom&transaction_subject=200703030249937&residence_country=AU&txn_type=web_accept&payment_date=23%3A36%3A36+Jan+11%2C+2014+PST&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1

Comment: I have edited my question recently. You can see a highlighted link and query URL am getting in screenshot.

Comment: looks like you are using javascript not `URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().getQuery()` ?

Comment: I used it in my controller and printed a debug messege. It is same as the other methods.

   String urlVal1 = URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().getQuery();
          system.debug('================================= New urlVal = ' + urlVal1 );
output : ================================= New urlVal = charset=windows-1252&payer_email=name%40company.net.au&receiver_email=paypal%40company.com.au&auth=A6P4OiUSwAL6901WUc3VK.fiUaYTR5AND5h.XpBaMqrI8gSmid.n0tFsfAMP6u3unDXUuiABwGtZWQlN.RFtDcA&payer_status=verified&receiver_id=GDGRD3PAZBMD8

Comment: use this buddy `URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm()`

Comment: Can you pass a parameter randomly to check like

http://ratan.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/NEWOPP?S=params&A=paramA&Z=paramZ&B=paramB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33504/discussion-between-rishi-and-ratan).